# Symfony 2 SecurityBundle Authentication via form login raises BadCredentialsException

Tags: symfony

This is my Entity:

```
<?php

namespace Trade\TradeBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints as Assert;
use Symfony\Bridge\Doctrine\Validator\Constraints\UniqueEntity;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\UserInterface;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass = "Trade\TradeBundle\Repository\UserRepository")
 * @ORM\Table(name = "user")
 * @UniqueEntity(fields = "username", message = "The username already exists.")
 */
class User implements UserInterface
{
/**
 * @ORM\id
 * @ORM\Column(name = "id", type = "integer")
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy = "AUTO")
 */
protected $id;

/**
 * @ORM\Column(name = "username", type = "string", length = 20, unique = true)
 *
 * @Assert\NotBlank(
 *      message = "The username cannot be blank."
 * )
 */
protected $username;

/**
 * @ORM\Column(name = "password", type = "string", length = 40)
 *
 * @Assert\NotBlank(
 *      message = "The password cannot be blank."
 * )
 * @Assert\MinLength(
 *      limit = 8,
 *      message = "The password '{{ value }}' is too short. It should have {{ limit }} characters or more."
 * )
 * @Assert\MaxLength(
 *      limit = 16,
 *      message = "The password '{{ value }}' is too long. It should have {{ limit }} characters or less."
 * )
 */
protected $password;

/**
 * @ORM\Column(type = "string", length = 40)
 */
protected $salt;

public function __construct()
{
    $this->salt = md5(uniqid(null, true));
}

/**
 * Get id
 *
 * @return integer
 */
public function getId()
{
    return $this->id;
}

/**
 * Set username
 *
 * @param string $username
 */
public function setUsername($username)
{
    $this->username = $username;
}

/**
 * Get username
 *
 * @return string
 */
public function getUsername()
{
    return $this->username;
}

/**
 * Set password
 *
 * @param string $password
 */
public function setPassword($password)
{
    $this->password = $password;
}

/**
 * Get password
 *
 * @return string
 */
public function getPassword()
{
    return $this->password;
}

public function getSalt()
{
    return $this->salt;
}

public function getRoles()
{
    return array('ROLE_USER');
}

public function eraseCredentials()
{
}

public function equals(UserInterface $user)
{
    return $this->username === $user->getUsername();
}
}
```

This is my Repository:

```
<?php

namespace Trade\TradeBundle\Repository;

use Doctrine\ORM\EntityRepository;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\UserProviderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\UserInterface;

/**
 * UserRepository
 *
 * This class was generated by the Doctrine ORM. Add your own custom
 * repository methods below.
 */
class UserRepository extends EntityRepository implements UserProviderInterface
{
public function loadUserByUsername($username)
{
    return $this->getEntityManager()->findOneByUsername($username);
}

public function refreshUser(UserInterface $user)
{
    return $this->loadUserByUsername($user->getUsername());
}

public function supportsClass($class)
{
    return $class === 'Trade\TradeBundle\Entity\User';
}
}
```

This is security.yml:

```
security:
    encoders:
        Trade\TradeBundle\Entity\User:
            algorithm: sha1
            encode_as_base64: false
            iterations: 1

role_hierarchy:
    ROLE_ADMIN:       ROLE_USER
    ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN: [ROLE_USER, ROLE_ADMIN, ROLE_ALLOWED_TO_SWITCH]

providers:
    main:
        entity: { class: TradeTradeBundle:User, property: username }

firewalls:
    dev:
        pattern:  ^/(_(profiler|wdt)|css|images|js)/
        security: false

    secured_area:
        pattern:    ^/
        form_login:
            check_path: /account/signin_check
            login_path: /account/signin
        logout:
            path:   /account/signout
            target: /
        anonymous: ~

access_control:
    - { path: ^/account/signin, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
    - { path: ^/account, roles: ROLE_USER }
    - { path: ^/admin, roles: ROLE_ADMIN }
```

This is my Controller action:

```
/**
 * @Route("/account/signin", name = "account_signin")
 * @Route("/account/signin_check", name = "account_signin_check")
 * @Method({"GET", "POST"})
 */
public function signInAction()
{
    $request = $this->getRequest();
    $session = $request->getSession();

    $user = new \Trade\TradeBundle\Entity\User();
    $form = $this->createForm(new \Trade\TradeBundle\Form\Type\UserType(), $user);

    if ($request->attributes->has(SecurityContext::AUTHENTICATION_ERROR))
    {
        $error = $request->attributes->get(SecurityContext::AUTHENTICATION_ERROR);
    }
    else
    {
        $error = $session->get(SecurityContext::AUTHENTICATION_ERROR);
        $session->remove(SecurityContext::AUTHENTICATION_ERROR);
    }

    return $this->render('TradeTradeBundle:Account:signin.html.twig', array('form' => $form->createView(), 'error' => $error));
}
```

This is my Form Class:

```
<?php

namespace Trade\TradeBundle\Form\Type;

use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilder;


class UserType extends AbstractType
{
public function buildForm(FormBuilder $builder, array $options)
{
    $builder->add('username', 'text', array('required' => false));
    $builder->add('password', 'password', array('required' => false));
}

public function getName()
{
    return 'user';
}

public function getDefaultOptions(array $options)
{
    return array(
        'data_class' => 'Trade\TradeBundle\Entity\User'
    );
}
}
```

This is my Form:

```
{% if error %}
    <div class="alert alert-error">{{ error }}</div>
{% endif %}
<form action="{{ path('account_signin_check') }}" method="post" class="form-inline" novalidate>
    <table class="table">
        <tr>
            <td style="width: 120px;">{{ form_label(form.username) }} <span class="required">*</span></td>
            <td style="width: 220px;">{{ form_widget(form.username, { 'attr': {'placeholder': 'Username'} }) }}</td>
            <td class="form-error" id="email_error">{{ form_errors(form.username) }}</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>{{ form_label(form.password) }} <span class="required">*</span></td>
            <td>{{ form_widget(form.password, { 'attr': {'placeholder': 'Password'} }) }}</td>
            <td class="form-error" id="password_error">{{ form_errors(form.password) }}</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="2" style="text-align: right;">
                {{ form_rest(form) }}
                <input type="reset" value="Cancel" class="btn" />
                <input type="submit" value="Sign in" class="btn btn-danger" />
            </td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</form>
```

When I try to login, BadCredentialsException is shown. I don't know why. I think I did everything right according to Symfony's documentation  Please, help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with the input names like this _username and _password or in your security.yml try to put this under secured_area

```
username_parameter: username
password_parameter: password
```

Maybe it helps you !

Answer (score 0):

This is pretty old but I hope my answer can help others.

I got exactly the same issue trying to mix usage of the form component with the security one.

Unfortunately this not possible since the security component relies on input form "name" parameters (html definition of name) **_username** and **_password** when calling the login_check function. That CANNOT be defined with the form component (no way to define this optional parameter of an input element).

When giving a name to the element with

> ->add('my_name',...

actually this is the id parameter of the element that is informed and not the "name" parameter. The "name" given by the buidlForm function will be "somename[my_name]" (where somename is the value returned by the getName() function of the Form class) that cannot be "_username" as required by the security component.

Maybe one workaround would be to define username_parameter as "somename[my_name]" in the security definition file so the component look for it but I haven't even tried this since this is a very nasty hack.

EDIT:
Actually one another workaround I used for another problem is to return an empty string in the getName() function of the Form class so we get: "my_name" as the input element attribute instead of "somename[my_name]".
So maybe we can try to give the "_username" and "_password" value to the name attribute (haven't tried).